# Vue won't read JSON response?

Tags: json, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

If `/scheduled_jobs/list` returns a JSON object, why is my Vue component not reading it?

Here's the component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul v-if="jobs.length">
            <li v-for="job in jobs">
        {{ job.id }}
        {{ job.document_id }}
        {{ job.user_id }}
        {{ job.schedule }}
        {{ job.status }}
      </li>
        </ul>
        <p v-else>
            Nothing waiting.
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        jobs: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      loadData () {
        $.get('/scheduled_jobs/list', function (response) {
          this.jobs = response.json()
        }.bind(this))
      },
      ready () {
        this.loadData()

        setInterval(function () {
          this.loadData()
        }.bind(this), 30000)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And here's the response from the URL:

```
{
  "id": "8154e79383a950072823410e",
  "document_id": 59455,
  "user_id": 2,
  "schedule": "2018-02-03T12:00",
  "status": 2
}
```

I just get this response:

```
Nothing waiting.
```

Comment: Are you not just setting the value of `jobs` to an object in your callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are overwriting the array with an object:

```
methods: {
      loadData () {
        $.get('/scheduled_jobs/list', function (response) {
          this.jobs.push(response.json());
        }.bind(this))
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an object, not an array, so `jobs.length` is `undefined`.